# Parametric equations intuition

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, parametric

If I paramaterise a function like x= f(t) and y=g(t) like x=t and y=t^2 why why does eliminating the parameter give you the function that the parametric equations? It may be clear for y=x^2 but i'm not why it is the case for functions like x=cost and y=sint.

Comment: You should get $y=x^2$ in this case. I'm not sure what you mean by getting a point.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "the x,y,t plane"? By "the intersection"? What point do you mean? If you eliminate the variable $t$ in those two equations you do end up with $y=x^2$. Please clarify.

Comment: What I meant was the that why does eliminating the parameter give you the function that the parametric equations represent @RoryDaulton

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes in your premise that "eliminating the parameter give you the function [for] the parametric equations."

First, eliminating the parameter may not result in a *function*, meaning that $y$ may not be a function of $x$. In your example $x=\cos t$ and $y=\sin t$, eliminating the parameter ends up with the equation

$$x^2+y^2=1$$

But that is not the graph of a function, since for any $y$ where $-1<y<1$ there are two corresponding values of $x$, not just one. The graph is a circle, which does not pass the vertical line test. The same is true if we try to make $x$ a function of $y$. Therefore we end up with a relation between $x$ and $y$ but not a function.

Your second mistake is that eliminating the parameter from the two equations resulting in one equation in just $x$ and $y$ may end up with an Cartesian equation with a graph different from the original parametric one. For example, consider the parametric equations

$$x=t^2, \quad y=t^2+1$$

Eliminating $t$ from those equations, in any of several ways, results in the Cartesian equation

$$y=x+1$$

The graph of that is a line that has parts in the first, second, and third quadrants. However, the original parametric equations define a *ray* that lies only within the first quadrant (and one point on the positive $y$ axis, $(0,1)$). The Cartesian equation *contains* the parametric equations but is not equivalent to them.

So a correct statement is to say that eliminating the parameter variable (when possible) results in a Cartesian equation that whose graph contains the graph of the original parametric equations. I.e. all points in the parametric graph satisfy the Cartesian equation, but additional points may also satisfy it.

Is that clear? And do you understand why my final statement is true?

Comment: May you clarify on why your last statement is true, please? I'm not sure on why all points in the parametric graph satisfy the $\textbf{original}$ cartesian equation. Is it because the parametric formulations arose due to considering the cartesian equations first?

Comment: and why does eliminating the variable (when possible) yields the original cartesian equations? @Rory Daulton

Comment: @mathsssislife: I never said the Cartesian equation is original--every time I write "original" I mean the parametric equations. (I just made a slight edit to make that more clear in my penultimate paragraph.) Every parametric point satisfies the Cartesian equation because that is how the Cartesian equation was derived--each step in the derivation is true for all the original points, so the final equation is also true. But additional points may also make that equation true.

Comment: In essence, when parameterizing a function, we create a mapping (always bijective?) and then to eliminate the variable (we compose functions), how can I prove that the composition always yields the function?

Comment: I'm not considering cases where they are of the form y=f(x) and then parametrising in terms of x=t and y=f(t), i'm considering cases when this is not the case.

Comment: @mathsssislife: I do not understand the question in your next-to-last comment or the kind of parameterization you mean in your last comment. But this is becoming too much of a conversation or chat, which is not the purpose of this site. If you have another question, ask it as another question, but make sure the question is more clear and specific than your last comments.